# Delete parent object hierarchy in code

Tags: scripting

How can I delete hierarchy of objects in code?
When trying to delete the "parent_obj", it's written in the GUI tooltip:

```
bpy.ops.outliner.object_operation(type='DELETE_HIERARCHY')
```

I tried to select the "parent_obj" using this code:

```
context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['parent_obj']
```

But got this error:

```
File "~/blender-2.76-rc2-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.76/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.outliner.object_operation.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

---

### Edit

Ok, I've found how to bypass this problem. Instead of using bpy.ops.outliner.object_operation(), I first select the objects hierarchy, and then used bpy.ops.object.delete():

```
bpy.data.objects[obj_name].select = True
for child in bpy.data.objects[obj_name].children:
    child.select = True
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: Have you searched for "context is incorrect" on this site yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should deseleted all the objects, select and remove the animation data from all the objects in the hierarchy, and call `bpy.ops.object.delete()`:

```
def delete_hierarchy(parent_obj_name):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj = bpy.data.objects[parent_obj_name]
    obj.animation_data_clear()
    names = set()
    # Go over all the objects in the hierarchy like @zeffi suggested:
    def get_child_names(obj):
        for child in obj.children:
            names.add(child.name)
            if child.children:
                get_child_names(child)

    get_child_names(obj)

    print(names)
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    [setattr(objects[n], 'select', True) for n in names]
    # Remove the animation from the all the child objects
    for child_name in names:
        bpy.data.objects[child_name].animation_data_clear()

    result = bpy.ops.object.delete()
    if result == {'FINISHED'}:
        print ("Successfully deleted object")
    else:
        print ("Could not delete object")
```

Comment: [setattr(objects[n], 'select', True) for n in names] doesn't work in 2022, and the code can not delete the parent_obj right now.

Comment: @tac pls don't change the answer as this one works perfectly for the blender version 2.76 it was intended. consider adding another answer for what works in the newer versions.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for your advice. I have post a new answer for what works in the newer versions.

Comment: @Tac cool thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your own solution probably works fine in your case, but the general case where the hierarchy is a bit more nested (children of children) might still deserve a solution.

perhaps something recursive:

```
import bpy

def delete_hierarchy(obj):
    names = set([obj.name])

    # recursion
    def get_child_names(obj):
        for child in obj.children:
            names.add(child.name)
            if child.children:
                get_child_names(child)

    get_child_names(obj)

    print(names)
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    [setattr(objects[n], 'select', True) for n in names]

    bpy.ops.object.delete()

delete_hierarchy(bpy.context.active_object)
```

This function assumes no objects are currently selected, and accumulates the names of the hierarchy starting with the main object ( i used active_object, but you can pass any object reference there ). Then it selects all the found names, then runs the `object_delete` operator.

Comment: I found that bpy.ops.object.delete() doesn't delete a nested animation objects. I inserted keyframes to the parent objects, and they weren't been deleted. Any ideas?

Comment: you want to remove all keyframes from each object in this hierarchy.?

Comment: Yes. In my case, only the parent obj has keyframes.

Comment: I dont have a file at hand with any complicated animation, perhaps share one on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - can be a trivial one to show what you mean, before and after.

Comment: Please find this example. I removed everything else and left only the parent obj with the animation.
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=859" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/859/)

Comment: Apparently, one should first call parent_obj.animation_data_clear()

Comment: If you've solved your own question. we encourage you to write your own answer and even accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

@[p2or](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3710/p2or) and @[Noam Peled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/16364/noam-peled) have given a good idea, but `[setattr(objects[n], 'select', True) for n in names]` doesn't work in 2022, and their code can't delete the `parent_obj` right now.
So I modified their code to work with Blender 3.0 and higher.

```
def delete_hierarchy(parent_obj_name):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj = bpy.data.objects[parent_obj_name]
    obj.animation_data_clear()
    names = set()
    # Go over all the objects in the hierarchy like @zeffi suggested:
    def get_child_names(obj):
        for child in obj.children:
            names.add(child.name)
            if child.children:
                get_child_names(child)

    get_child_names(obj)
    names.add(parent_obj_name)
    print(names)
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    
    # Remove the animation from the all the child objects
    if names:
        for child_name in names:
            bpy.data.objects[child_name].animation_data_clear()
            objects[child_name].select_set(state=True)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(objects[child_name])
        print ("Successfully deleted object")
    else:
        print ("Could not delete object")
```